# External hard drive unmounts when spun down

Tags: external-hard-drive, ext4, fstab, powersave

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 5 with an external hard drive connected via USB 3. On boot, it is mounted with the following entry in /etc/fstab:

```
LABEL=external /mnt/external ext4 defaults,noatime,nofail 0 2
```

This works well, and I've had no issues. But because this drive only really runs for backups and as a Jellyfin server, I'd like to spin it down when not in use.

`hd-idle` and `hdparm` didn't support it, but using `sdparm` I could set the `STANDBY_Z` time and enable it. The drive does spin down exactly as wanted after 10 minutes.

The issue: When trying to access the drive, I can hear it spin back up, but nothing is mounted (/mnt/external is empty). I suspect that the drive is unmounted when it spins down, because if I (manually) run `sudo mount -a` everything works fine again.

As for things I've already tried: the drive shows no issue when not going to sleep, and on windows it can spin down and back up just fine. Additionally, I think I can exclude power delivery issues. The hard drive has an external power brick and the Pi uses the official 5V 5A power supply.

I have an entire log I can share. It begins at boot, at 14:37 I try to access /mnt/external. Two minutes later, I run `sudo mount -a`. I don't really understand what's going on, does anyone have any idea?

```
journalctl --dmesg | grep sd
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci-brcmstb 1000fff000.mmc: there is not valid maps for state default
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15628053167 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.28 TiB)
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel:  sda: sda1
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 06 13:53:09 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan 06 13:53:09 rpi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Jan 06 13:53:11 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: opcode=0x8a 8a 00 00 00 00 00 06 dd 78 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=5s
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: opcode=0x8a 8a 00 00 00 00 00 06 dd 78 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 115177480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 77137441 starting block 14397185)
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 14396929
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 7814258448 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 11 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 7814252544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 7814252544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 976781312, lost sync page write
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: JBD2: I/O error when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 15628053167 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.28 TiB)
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
Jan 06 14:31:44 rpi kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Jan 06 14:31:44 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 06 14:37:15 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:29 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:39:56 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): recovery complete
Jan 06 14:39:56 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
tfaehse@rpi:~ $ journalctl --dmesg | grep sd
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sdhci-brcmstb 1000fff000.mmc: there is not valid maps for state default
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 15628053167 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.28 TiB)
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 4096-byte physical blocks
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel:  sda: sda1
Jan 06 13:53:05 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 06 13:53:09 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan 06 13:53:09 rpi kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
Jan 06 13:53:11 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: opcode=0x8a 8a 00 00 00 00 00 06 dd 78 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 UNKNOWN(0x2003) Result: hostbyte=0x01 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=5s
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#13 CDB: opcode=0x8a 8a 00 00 00 00 00 06 dd 78 08 00 00 00 08 00 00
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: I/O error, dev sda, sector 115177480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): ext4_end_bio:343: I/O error 10 writing to inode 77137441 starting block 14397185)
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: Buffer I/O error on device sda1, logical block 14396929
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 7814258448 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 11 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 7814252544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: device offline error, dev sda, sector 7814252544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 2
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 976781312, lost sync page write
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: JBD2: I/O error when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
Jan 06 14:31:30 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=0x07 driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 15628053167 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 TB/7.28 TiB)
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Preferred minimum I/O size 4096 bytes
Jan 06 14:31:31 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of preferred minimum block size (4096 bytes)
Jan 06 14:31:44 rpi kernel:  sdb: sdb1
Jan 06 14:31:44 rpi kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Jan 06 14:37:15 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:29 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:37:30 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sda1): dx_probe:822: inode #77137068: lblock 0: comm smbd[192.168.17: error -5 reading directory block
Jan 06 14:39:56 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): recovery complete
Jan 06 14:39:56 rpi kernel: EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
```

Last but not least, this is all the hard drive info sdparm can read:

```
sudo sdparm --flexible -6 -l -a /dev/sdb
    /dev/sdb: Seagate   Expansion HDD     1801
    Direct access device specific parameters: WP=0  DPOFUA=0
Caching (SBC) [ca] mode page:
  IC            0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Initiator control
  ABPF          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Abort pre-fetch
  CAP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Caching analysis permitted
  DISC          1  [cha: n, def:  1, sav:  1]  Discontinuity
  SIZE          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Size enable
  WCE           1  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  1]  Write cache enable
  MF            0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Multiplication factor
  RCD           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Read cache disable
  DRRP          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Demand read retention priority
  WRP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Write retention priority
  DPTL          -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Disable pre-fetch transfer length
  MIPF          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Minimum pre-fetch
  MAPF          -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Maximum pre-fetch
  MAPFC         -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Maximum pre-fetch ceiling
  FSW           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Force sequential write
  LBCSS         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Logical block cache segment size
  DRA           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Disable read ahead
  SYNC_PROG     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Synchronous cache progress indication
  NV_DIS        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Non-volatile cache disable
  NCS           -1  [cha: n, def: -1, sav: -1]  Number of cache segments
  CSS           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Cache segment size
Control [co] mode page:
  TST           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Task set type
  TMF_ONLY      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Task management functions only
  DPICZ         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Disable protection information check if protect field zero
  D_SENSE       0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Descriptor format sense data
  GLTSD         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Global logging target save disable
  RLEC          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Report log exception condition
  QAM           1  [cha: n, def:  1, sav:  1]  Queue algorithm modifier
  NUAR          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  No unit attention on release
  QERR          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Queue error management
  VS_CTL        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Vendor specific [byte 4, bit 7]
  RAC           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Report a check
  UA_INTLCK     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Unit attention interlocks control
  SWP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Software write protect
  ATO           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Application tag owner
  TAS           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Task aborted status
  ATMPE         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Application tag mode page enabled
  RWWP          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Reject write without protection
  SBLP          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Supported block lengths and protection information
  AUTOLOAD      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Autoload mode
  BTP           0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Busy timeout period (100us)
  ESTCT         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Extended self test completion time (sec)
Power condition [po] mode page:
  PM_BG         0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Power management, background functions, precedence
  STANDBY_Y     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Standby_y timer enable
  IDLE_C        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_c timer enable
  IDLE_B        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_b timer enable
  IDLE_A        0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_a timer enable
  STANDBY_Z     1  [cha: y, def:  1, sav:  1]  Standby_z timer enable
  IACT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_a condition timer (100 ms)
  SZCT          6000  [cha: y, def:9000, sav:6000]  Standby_z condition timer (100 ms)
  IBCT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_b condition timer (100 ms)
  ICCT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Idle_c condition timer (100 ms)
  SYCT          0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  Standby_y condition timer (100 ms)
  CCF_IDLE      0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  check condition if from idle_c
  CCF_STAND     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  check condition if from a standby
  CCF_STOPP     0  [cha: n, def:  0, sav:  0]  check condition if from stopped
```